# JDialog does not fire closing or closed event when button pressed

Tags: java, swing

When clicking the "X" button on the window frame of a JDialog

- the closing event is fired, and
- the application exits.

When clicking the "Ok" button

- the window disappears,
- no closing event is fired, and
- the application does not exit.

Why? And how do I get the two to behave the same; I'd like them both to fire a closing event. I do not want to create a custom button. I want the defaults of the look and feel for the current operating system to dictate the button text and style so that it is consistent with the running OS.

I've observed this behavior on macOS, Windows, in Java 11 and Java 13. So I'm guessing it is intentional... but it sure baffles me. I thought any `setVisible(false)` would trigger a closing event.

Here's my SSCCE:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JexitOnClose2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()-> {
            final JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(
                    new JLabel("hello"), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, "title goes here");
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.addWindowListener(
                new WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("window closing");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("window closed");
                    }
                }
            );
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a little time to dig through the source code - from my 3 minutes of investigation, `windowClosed` is only called when `dispose` is called - `setVisible` doesn't `dispose` of the window

Comment: Change `dialog.setVisible(true);` to `dialog.setVisible(true); dialog.dispose();` to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson and @MadProgrammer.

I regret a bit that I mentioned `setVisible(false);` because I'm actually concerned about the disparity in behavior between the `Ok` button and the frame's close button. I'm not setting the dialog visibility to `false`... some internal JDK code is doing that.

But I think @AndrewThompson, you are right. I have to dispose after `setVisible(true);` And I now do something like that in the code and the behavior is consistent.

Comment: Note that I have nothing more of consequence to add, and also that only one person can be notified per comment, so @MadProgrammer is likely unaware of your last comment.

Comment: *"I now do something like that in the code and the behavior is consistent."* Glad you got it sorted! Also plus 1 for adding code to make it easy for others to work on the problem. It's one of those uncommon problems where I would not make suggestions before testing what I was proposing.